# Compute $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\text{arctan}\left(e^{-x}\right)\text{d}x$

Tags: improper-integrals

I think I've shown that the integral $I$ defined by
$$
 I=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\text{arctan}\left(e^{-x}\right)\text{d}x
$$
exists and I wonder what is its value.

The function $s :x \mapsto \text{arctan}\left(e^{-x}\right)$ is continuous and positive on $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ and
$$
\text{arctan}\left(e^{-x}\right)\underset{(+\infty)}{\sim}e^{-x}=o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)
$$
The function $\displaystyle x \mapsto \frac{1}{x^2}$ is integrable on $\left[1,+\infty\right[$ so $s$ is integrable on $\left[1,+\infty\right[$ and by continuity on $\left[0,1\right]$, $s$ is integrable on $\left[0,+\infty\right[$.

How can I compute it ?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+arctan(e%5Ex)

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main
page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730)
for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set $u=e^{-x}$ so that:
\begin{align}
I:=\int^\infty_0 \arctan(e^{-x})\,dx=\int^1_0 \frac{\arctan(u)}{u}\,du
\end{align}
Using taylor series of the $\arctan$ we get:
\begin{align}
I=\int^1_0 \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} u^{2k}\,du = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int^1_0 \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} u^{2k}\,du = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}=G
\end{align}
where $G$ is the [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant). Surely the interchanging of  summation and integration must be justified. That can be easily done by using  the fact that the  series converges uniformly on any compact interval in $[0,1)$.

Comment: (+1) I didn't delete my answer because it is not *exactly* the same, but if you think it is too close, I will.

Comment: There is no need to! How can I think that while yours has a shortcut?! (+1) for yours too!

Answer (score 5):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\arctan\left(e^{-x}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{e^{-(2k+1)x}}{2k+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac1{(2k+1)^2}\\[6pt]
&=\mathrm{G}
\end{align}
$$
As noted by Shashi, $\mathrm{G}$ is [Catalan's Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).